# how to encode bytes to separate item in list in android

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android, I have an encodeBytes that contains some items. I want separate all item from encodeByte and show in spinner. Check below code, in that **data** variable having all items in single string, I want iterate each item and add to **list**

Here my code:

```
private void waitForResponse(InputStream mmInputStream, long timeout) throws IOException {
    int bytesAvailable;

    while (true) {
        bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();
        if (bytesAvailable > 0) {
            byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
            byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024];
            mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);

            for (int i = 0; i < bytesAvailable; i++) {
                byte b = packetBytes[i];

                if (b == delimiter) {
                    byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                    System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                    final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");  **//Its show all item in single string,I want separate and each item add in list**
                    writeOutput("Received:" + data);                       
                    list.add(data);                        
                    return;
                } else {
                    readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**data** variable having like this :

```
Security Check Corp_2 Tender Security Check Corp_1
```

I want like this in list:

```
Security Check
Corp_2                                                                     
Tender
Security Check
Corp_1
```

Comment: How are the items separated?

Comment: I dont have idea, But i want to show the item in spinner

Comment: You'll need a separator to separate the items. e.g. if your separator is `|`, your data will look like this: `Security|Check Corp_2|Tender|Security Check|Corp_1`

Comment: How to append separator to data

Comment: You won't be able to append a separator here, you have to append it at the source from where you are getting this response.